# Why should I use Free and not FreeAndNil in a destructor?

Tags: delphi, destructor, delphi-2007

I have read [A case against FreeAndNil](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2010/02/05/38910) but still don't understand why I cannot use this method in a class destructor ? Can anyone explain.

**Update:** I think the comment from [Eric Grange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76349/eric-grange) was most useful for me. The link show that this is not obvious how to deal with it and it is mainly a matter of taste. Also the method FreeAndInvalidate was useful.

Comment: You asked a nice question here.

Answer (score 16):

> The problem with that is that many
>   seem to use FreeAndNil as some magic
>   bullet that will slay that mysterious
>   crash dragon. If using FreeAndNil() in
>   the destructor seems to solve a crash
>   or other memory corruption problems,
>   then you should be digging deeper into
>   the real cause. When I see this, the
>   first question I ask is, why is the
>   instance field being accessed after
>   that instance was destroyed? That
>   typically points to a design problem.

It argues that it hides the real problem you have. It must mean your code is accessing properties/fields/methods of an object that is already destroyed (the destructor is called). So instead of hiding the real problem with FreeAndNil you should really be solving the underlying problem.

This code below would not crash if you would use FreeAndNil PropertyA in the destructor of SomeObject. But it hides the real problem that SomeObject is used after it is destroyed. It is better to solve this design problem (accessing destroyed objects) instead of hiding it.

```
SomeObject.Free;  // Destructor called
if Assigned(SomeObject.PropertyA) then  // SomeObject is destroyed, but still used
  SomeObject.PropertyA.Method1;
```

**EDIT**

On the other case, one could argue that if FreeAndNil is not used, the code would not crash either. Since even though the object is destroyed, the memory might not be reused and all structures might be in tact. The code above might even run without problems if Free is used to destroy PropertyA instead of FreeAndNil.

And if FreeAndNil was used to destroy SomeObject, you would also see the real problem no matter what the code in the destructor is.

So although I agree with the argument that it could hide the real design flaw and personally do not use FreeAndNil in destructors, it is not some magic bullet to discover such design flaws.

Comment: The problem that NOT using FreeAndNIL ignores is if your destructor encounters an exception, leaving an undestroyed object that could conceivably be subject to another attempt to destroy.  In which case, already Free'd objects should of course not be free'd again.  FreeAndNIL protects against incomplete destructors.  There is an argument that an incomplete destructor reflects bad design also, but sadly you aren't always in control of precisely what will occur in your destructors (e.g. if you destroy other objects whose destructor behaviour you do not directly control or easy change)

Comment: For protection, you can use something like 'FreeAndInvalidate' (http://delphitools.info/2010/02/06/dont-abuse-freeandnil-anymore/) to make the reference invalid and not just nil, so that all further attemps to access the object will trigger an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That give me some insight.

Answer (score 9):

The issue is fairly easy to explain, and the contention around this issue is more subjective than objective.   The use of FreeAndNil is simply unnecessary if the variable reference to the object being freed will go out of scope:

```
procedure Test;
var
  LObj: TObject;
begin
  LObj := TObject.Create;
  try
    {...Do work...}
  finally
    //The LObj variable is going out of scope here,
    // so don't bother nilling it.  No other code can access LObj.

    //FreeAndNil(LObj);
    LObj.Free;
  end; 
end;
```

In the above code snippet, nilling the `LObj` variable would be pointless, for the reason given.   However, if an object variable can be instantiated and freed several times during the lifetime of an app, then it becomes necessary to check whether the object is indeed instantiated or not.   The easy way to check this is whether the object reference has been set to `nil`.   In order to facilitate that setting to `nil`, the `FreeAndNil()` method will both free the resources, and set `nil` for you.   Then, in code you can check to see whether the object is instantiated with either `LObj = nil` or `Assigned(LObj)`.

The case of whether to use `.Free` or `FreeAndNil()` in object destructors is a grey area, but for the most part, `.Free` should be safe, and nilling the references to sub-objects in the destructor should be unnecessary.  There are various arguments around how to deal with exceptions in constructors and destructors.

Now pay attention: if you prefer to pick and choose whether to use `.Free` or `FreeAndNil()` depending on the specific circumstances outlined above, that's fine, but note that the cost of a bug due to *not* nilling a freed object reference that is subsequently accessed can be very high.   If the pointer is subsequently accessed (object freed but reference not set to nil), it can happen that you are unlucky and the detection of memory corruption occurs many lines of code away from the access to the freed-but-unnilled object reference.   This kind of bug can take a very long time to fix, and yes, I know how to use FastMM.

Therefore for some people, including me, it has become habit (a lazy one, perhaps) to simply nil all object pointers when they're freed, even when the nilling is not strictly necessary.

Comment: You are treating a single case where you have a tiny procedure where the variable goes out of scope. There is more than that. But +1, I agree with using FreeAndNil.

Comment: @Altar: I selected this example because it provides the very best situation in which it can be argued that "Free" is better than "FreeAndNil".  All other situations are less precise.  To reiterate: I *always* nil my object references when destroying object instances, so that I never have to think about whether I need to or not.

Answer (score 5):

I tended to use `FreeAndNil` fairly often (for whatever reason) but not anymore. What made me stop doing this is not related to whether the variable needs to be `nil` afterwards or not. It is related to code changes, especially type changes of variables.

I got bitten several times after changing the type of a variable from `TSomething` to an interface type `ISomething`. `FreeAndNil` doesn't complain and happily continues doing its job on the interface variable. This sometimes lead to mysterious crashes which could not be immediately followed back to the place where it happened and took some time to find.

So I switched back to calling `Free`. And when I deem it necessary I set the variable to `nil` afterwards explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

i hunted down a stackoverflow question talking about `FreeAndNil` and `FreeAndInvalidate` to mention that the Microsoft Security Development Lifecycle now [recommends something *similar* to `FreeAndInvalidate`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sdl/archive/2012/04/24/guarding-against-re-use-of-stale-object-references.aspx):

> In light of the SDL recommendation above – and a number of real bugs related to reuse of stale references to deleted C++ objects...
>
> The obvious choice of sanitization value is NULL. However there are downsides to that: we know that a large number of application crashes are due to NULL pointer dereferences. Choosing NULL as a sanitization value would mean that new crashes introduced by this feature may be less likely to stand out to a developer as needing a proper solution – i.e. proper management of C++ object lifetimes – rather than just a NULL check that suppresses the immediate symptom.
>
> Also checks for NULL are a common code construct meaning that an existing check for NULL combined with using NULL as a sanitization value could fortuitously hide a genuine memory safety issue whose root cause really does needs addressing.
>
> For this reason we have chosen 0x8123 as a sanitization value – from an operating system perspective this is in the same memory page as the zero address (NULL), but an access violation at 0x8123 will better stand out to the developer as needing more detailed attention.

So basically:

```
procedure FreeAndInvalidate(var obj);
var
   temp : TObject;
const 
   INVALID_ADDRESS = $8123; //address on same page as zero address (nil)
begin
   //Note: Code is public domain. No attribution required.
   temp := TObject(obj);
   Pointer(obj) := Pointer(INVALID_ADDRESS);
   temp.Free;
end;
```